# How do I access the child nodes in this JSON hierarchy?

Tags: javascript, json, parsing

I don't know how to access the child nodes (i.e. "exDate", "paymentDate", etc...).

This is the format I am given on the IEX Cloud API. I'm not sure what to do since each section starts with a number (but I have confirmed that its type is a string).

Here is the link to the actual JSON page from IEX API:

[Link to IEX API JSON file I want to parse](https://cloud.iexapis.com/beta//stock/aapl/dividends/1y?token=pk_f32f8fa5fde946a08595782b7543410b)

Also, if I were going to do this in Firefox Web Console, how would I access "exDate"?

Thank you

```js
 
0: 
exDate: "2019-02-08"
paymentDate: "2019-02-14"
recordDate: "2019-02-11"
declaredDate: "2019-01-29"
amount: 0.73
flag: "No Change QoQ"

1:
exDate: "2018-11-09"
paymentDate: "2018-11-15"
recordDate: "2018-11-12"
declaredDate: "2018-11-01"
amount: 0.73
flag: "No Change QoQ"

2: 
exDate: "2018-08-10"
paymentDate: "2018-08-16"
recordDate: "2018-08-13"
declaredDate: "2018-07-31"
amount: 0.73
flag: "No Change QoQ"

3: 
exDate: "2018-05-11"
paymentDate: "2018-05-17"
recordDate: "2018-05-14"
declaredDate: "2018-05-01"
amount: 0.73
flag: "Increase"
```

Comment: I'm trying to tackle this exact same issue right now.  Except I want to pull out the latest dividend amount straight from the URL itself without doing any json parsing.  https://github.com/iexg/IEX-API/issues/742

Answer (score 0):

The proper way is name[index].keyName. Each section starts with a number which is the index. You are viewing in firefox so it is autoformatting the JSON. View it as raw data and click the prettyprint option to view how the data actually looks. If I store the data in a variable called arr, I can access exDate like below:-

```
console.log(arr[0].exDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use bracket notation.

```
var json = JSON.parse(your_json_source);
// If the key is an integer
var exDate = json[0].exDate;
// If the key is a string
var exDate = json["0"].exDate;
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you so much.